# Joomla 2.5 check current page

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

In Joomla 2.5 how would i check which page the user is currently on? I have this which checks if they are on the home page:

```
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
```

I need something similar which will check if they are on another page in the site and return a different template. How would this be done?

Comment: In Joomla 2.5 you can set a template to a page on the site through the backend!!

Comment: this would probably be easier, but it was an old 1.5 template which i need to upgrade to joomla 2.5 so it was more efficient for me to use the code in my answer below :)

Comment: You assign the template to the menu items in the styles section of the template manager. Its not something that you need to do in the code at all - so it does't matter at all your upgrading a old 1.5 template. However at the end of the day it's whatever makes you happiest!!

Comment: the way the template was built, the two seperate templates where in onr index.php file, so to do it that way i would have had to seperate them out and then add it to the styles section, whereas this way i only had to add a couple of lines of code for it to work :D If you out your answer as an answer ill accept it!

Comment: ahh got ya! accept your own answer if its correct lol. It's what answers your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();

if ($active->id == 139){
//some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Joomla php check if user is viewing specific page.

There are several ways to differentiate your Front Page from other pages in your website.

$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();

echo $active->alias;